# How to recreate initial ASP.NET Identity Tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I went to upgrade our ASP.NET Web Forms solution from Identity 1.x to Identity 2.0. I updated the three Identity 2.0 packages. I then went to work on implementing Password Reset, etc. I didn't realize I had to [Update the Database](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/12/20/updating-asp-net-applications-from-asp-net-identity-1-0-to-2-0-0-alpha1.aspx). That migration failed because the tables were in the wrong context. We decided to start over. We deleted the tables but they are not getting recreated when I access the Login page. How do I get these tables regenerated or should I create them manually?

Comment: have you tried to register any user ? shouldn't asp.net identity be  regenerated identity db infrastructure by itself.

Comment: If you are using the WebPages framework, then in your AppStart file, you can specify a value of `true` for AutoCreateTables in: `InitializeDatabaseConnection("UserProfile", "UserId", "Email", true);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disabling the schema consistency. This is one time thing that needs to happen when you upgrade asp.net identity from version 1.0 to 2.0.

```
public ApplicationDbContext() : base("MyConnection", throwIfV1Schema:false)
```

Notice I added `throwIfV1Schema:false` as a second parameter. Compile it, try to log in so the DB gets updated, do the migrations if needed and then you can remove it.